# Handling milli vs micro seconds in python

Tags: python, utc, milliseconds

In python we could convert from UTC time ( Micro seconds since 1970) to a datetime object using

```
time_in_micro=1000000000
dt=datetime.fromtimestamp(time_in_micro)
```

time could also be in Milli Seconds. In that case we can multiply it by 1000 and use the fromtimestamp method.

however, is there a method which can handle Mill or Mirco seconds seamlessly ?
i.e it should work whether we pass milli or micro seconds

Comment: How would that be helpful? It would be less explicit, which is unpythonic. Do you not know which you're getting?

Comment: Thanks Jonrsharpe. Yeah , I do not know which will be input . It could be micro or milli. If i knew then it is easy .

Comment: Do you have an acceptable range? Are there any values the are valid within it in *both* micros and millis?

Answer (score 2):

Any such method would still require a way to indicate whether the argument was in milliseconds or microseconds:

```
# For example
datetime.hypothetical_fromtimestamp(100, units="milliseconds")       
datetime.hypothetical_fromtimestamp(100, units="microseconds")
```

This doesn't seem to be any more useful than just assuming the argument is in microseconds and scaling a millisecond argument accordingly.

Comment: Thanks chepner. Just wanted to make sure  that I am not missing any cool pythonic tricks .